# Anyone know of a C++ or Python library that will divide an image into pieces of arbitrary shape?

Tags: c++, python, qt, image-processing, pyqt

I'm working on a project involving puzzles made out of user-supplied images. I have been very hard-pressed to find a library that will serve my purposes. I would like to write the program in either Python or C++. I have been considering using Qt (or PyQt) to do it, so if you know of a library that will work with Qt it would be nice, though at this point anything would be nice.

Comment: Just a thought--images can be square as long as portions of the image are transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't expect to find a library for any specific task. In this case, you need image-processing library, which is able to:

- draw image region with transparent background. You have piece configuration, use it as a mask to cut out edges.
- save drawn image to some format.

Qt graphics is totally able to do all that.